# Saving datamapper relationship in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm starting with Datamapper and having some errors. I thought if I create an object, a related object and then I save the relationship, both the objects were saves as well.

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('id', $id)->get();

$p = new User_profile();
$p->name = 'xx';

$u->save($p);
```

Actually if I do like this, the profile is not saved. And of course not the relationship. If I do something like this:

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('id', $id)->get();

$p = new User_profile();
$p->save();
$p->name = 'xx';

$u->save($p);
```

both are saved but the profile is completly empty. None of the parameters are saved but the id and the Datamapper defaults (created and updated)

Is this behavior correct or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like if you may have not correctly set up the models. Could you post them too?

Comment: No, the models should be ok since it works in certain situations. I think it will has something to do with the answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/save.html under the *Save a New object and its Relations in a single call* and *Save an Existing object and its Relations in a single call* sections, it explains how datamapper handles this.

What is going on is that `save` is never called on the `User_profile()`. You need to be calling `save()` on the object that is not yet persisted, so this should work for you:

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('id', $id)->get();

$p = new User_profile();
$p->name = 'xx';

$p->save($u);
```

Comment: So I misunderstood the doc. Thank you for your answer, I will work it out and reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('id', $id)->get();

//passing the user object $u to the user_profile object ensures that
//data-mapper fills $p with any related information in the database if that exists
//or just the id attribute for the relationship.
//This way, $p will not be empty even though its fields might not b complete,
//but the relating attribute which should be 'user_id' will have a valid value
//in the 'profiles' table
$p = new User_profile($u);

$p->name = 'xx';

$u->save();
$p->save();
```

At the end of this, the object $p will now have the following value at the minimum

```
echo $p->user_id   //prints out $id;
echo $p->name      //prints out xx.
```

After calling the save method, they must definitely be saved as a new entry in the profiles table if the data does not exist before or as an update if the such row already exists.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't try yet but it seems to be quite correct.